# Python: Detecting non-specific inputs in lists

Tags: python, list, input, string-concatenation

My list is appended through selection. Basically, I ask a question, and whatever you input is what goes into this list.

I also ask how many of whatever you input. This created duplicates, so I used a concatenation to add an incremental number if the amount you entered is greater than one. (for example,

"What would you like to add to the list?"
User: "dog"
"How many?"
User: "3"

list = dog, dog2, dog3, cat)

For my specific program, there is no way of me knowing what the user might input, so I can't use `if ____ in _____` Can I? Also, now I have these concatenated strings named 'dog' and a number. I just want the code to detect dog, within the list, but again, **I don't know if dog is even in the list! It could be anything!**

Comment: Just to be clear, what exactly do you want your code to do/ what is the problem you face right now? Do you mean you want the code to know how many of each term was entered? (eg. you want the code to know that 'dog' corresponds to '3'?)

Comment: So, you want to detect something, but aren't quite sure _what_ you want to detect?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include this detail @ForceBru, The part I am specifically stuck on is, if you want to remove a certain item from this list, it has to be what actually is in the list. But some of the items in this list have numbers next to them, so to not produce duplicates...if this helps.

Comment: @jpcoder, why do you even write the duplicates to the list if you actually don't want them to be there?

Comment: @ForceBru I need to be less vague, it's my fault, sorry. The reason I am allowing them in the list is because a function is called based on what you input. However, I only want that function to run as many times as it is in your list... something like a card deck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description and the comments, here is a sample code which you need, I am creating a dict, and storing the item as key and the count as the value.

```
item = input("What would you like to add to the list?") # User Input : Dog
cnt = int(input("How many?")) : User Input : 3

d = {item:cnt} # dict created {'dog': '3'}

def callFunctionNtimes(d, key):
    """
    Function which check the key (dog) is present in the dict, if it is present call callYourFunction as many times as it is the value(count) of the key.
    """
    cnt = d.get(key, 0)
    for c in range(0, cnt):
        callYourFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using conversion between Set and list. When adding new inputs, convert your list to Set to avoid duplicate element; when you want to use some list properties, convert it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem that you describe, it is more useful if you use dictionary than a list. It can be implemented like this

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['dog'] = 3
```

Add what-ever-thing as a key of the dictionary and the how many as its value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to figure out what integer value a user inputted for 'how many', there are a number of ways you could do this. 
One would be to have a dictionary containing the data. 
For example,

```
>>> dict = {} 
>>> "What would you like to add to the list?" User: "dog" "How many?" User: "3"
>>> dict["dog"] = 3
>>> dict
dict = {'dog': 3}
>>> dict['cat'] = 2
dict = {'dog': 3, 'cat': 2}
>>> for key in dict:
>>>    print(key + ": " + str(dict[key]))
dog: 3
cat: 2
```

In this way, you can iterate through the different keys in the dictionary and be able to know 'how many' of each you have.

Each item in the dictionary will now correspond to its numerical value.